# More than one virtual host in Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: apache

I have tried to configure a new virtual host in apache. I have copied the default. Updated the paths. The conf looks like this

```
    <VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/video
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/video>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
               Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
         </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/video/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /home/ubuntu/video/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I ran the command

```
sudo a2ensite video
```

which gave messaage that virtual host successfully added and will run upon reload. But i am not able to access the same. I have checked the path `/home/ubuntu/video` where error.log, access.log files are also created. I am not able to find the solution as well as problem. I searched in the internet if anyone have same problem.

The following blog post: [Adding virtual hosts to Ubuntu Apache](http://brucewampler.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/adding-virtual-hosts-to-ubuntu-apache/), says in its update the we cannot create more than one virtual host. I have already a virtual host installed. Does this mean 2nd virtual host cannot be configured in Ubuntu for apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [these instructions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#port).

> If you try using `<VirtualHost name:port>` without the `NameVirtualHost name:port` or you try to use the `Listen` directive, your configuration will not work.

So make sure you have these directives outside the `<VirtualHost>` tag:

```
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081
```

You can also add:

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

to your `VirtualHost` section.

Comment: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/video:
Listen cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

Comment: Sorry - `Listen` and `NameVirtualHost` should be placed outside any `VirtualHost`